# WorkFlow Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, workflow, workflow-foundation

How to unit test the windows workflows?

Comment: Please specify your question and give an example, as it seems too broad right now. What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: See similar question already asked: > [Unit/Automated Testing in a workflow
> system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143183/unitautomated-testing-in-a-workflow-system)

Comment: I think Workflow activities are relatively testable.
Here's an entry from my blog about unit testing Workflow activities:
http://www.unit-testing.net/CurrentArticle/How-To-Write-Unit-Tests-For-Workflow-Activities.html

Answer (score 6):

K. Scott Allen has posted [this](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2006/08/02/5492.aspx), which provides an approach to unit testing custom activities (although he says that he is not satisfied). A similar approach is presented by Ron Jacobs [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/rjacobs/archive/2008/08/26/unit-testing-workflows.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/rjacobs/archive/2008/08/27/unit-testing-activities-with-windows-workflow-foundation.aspx).

Another approach is presented by Maurice [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2008/06/02/unit-testing-custom-workflow-activities.aspx) and [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2008/06/11/unit-testing-asynchronous-workflow-activities.aspx) (he uses [TypeMock](http://www.typemock.com/) as Will already [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182740/workflow-unit-testing#182888)).

Comment: The Ron Jacobs articles are very promising, especially the second one which contains a sample solution showing how to wire-up the WWF runtime to host the unit tests.

Answer (score 4):

[Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting](http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting%20Overview).

A library of helper classes and activities designed to make unit testing of workflows easier.

Looks like there's a Channel 9 video for it on the [downloads page](http://wf.codeplex.com/), too.

Comment: @jlafay Have you found it possible to test the value of a variable in a workflow service? Please look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672878/assert-the-value-of-a-wf-service-variable-during-a-unit-test) and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 3):

MS dropped the ball on making workflows easily mockable and testable.  If you want to do thorough tests on your custom activities you'll need to purchase a mocking framework that can mock sealed types such as [TypeMock.](http://www.typemock.com/)  Otherwise, you'll have to write your code around the limitations of Workflow.