# Windows Workflow - is this a good time to start?

Tags: workflow-foundation

I've heard rumors that the Windows Workflow team is re-implementing a lot of the existing framework for the next release.  My company has a couple projects that would probably work really well with Workflow, and I'm familiar with the basics of the framework now, but I'm concerned that if we try to start implementing these in WF now, we'll end up regretting it when things supposedly get better in the near future.

Should we wait for the next major release of workflow, or should we start exploring it now to better prepare ourselves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read this blog [Good-bye Windows Workflow Foundation see you in 2011](http://realworldsa.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/goodbyewindowsworkflowfoundationseeyouin2011.htm)

I've been looking at WF solutions as well, but am not convinced that it gives me anything too special just yet. After reading the blog post and associated links I'd be waiting for the 4.0 release before investing too heavily in it.

Answer (score 2):

I think now is as good a time as any to start learning nServiceBus.  I think it's hard to understand exactly why WWF is so complex afterwards...

Seriously, I know this is a "reject the question" answer, but you owe it to yourself to investigate the OSS alternatives to WWF.  I'd say they're all better...

Comment: are you thinking of WCF? I'm not an expert on WWF but I think nservicebus is an alternative to WCF, not WWF

Comment: Actually, it covers the functionality you need of WWF.  Take a look at Sagas (http://www.nservicebus.com/Sagas.aspx).  They were originally called workflows, but changed the name to avoid confusion with WWF.  Sagas are extremely simple, easy to understand, and actually solve the same problem as WWF does without over-complication.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article about working on 3.5 workflows with an eye on transitioning to 4.0:

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2008/12/17/windows-workflow-changes-direction-write-new-workflows-with-net-40-in-mind.aspx